# How to update Database with data from divs with same id

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to using Ajax to update the database to skip the standard submission and not refresh the page just update results (entries)

So, first I have a table with some data which is already saved into `links` table on my database

So here is my codes:

**1st links.php:**

```
<div id="links_list">
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Link</td>
        <td>Posted By</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
        $rows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `links` ");
        $totalLinks = $rows->num_rows;
        if($totalLinks == 0){
          echo "<tr><td colspan='5'><div class='' style='font-size: 16px;color: #F44336;background: #fff;width: fit-content;margin-left: 4px;'><i class='fa fa-meh-o'></i> <b>Error :</b> No LINK Has Been Added Yet.</div></td></tr>";
        } else {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) {
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td id="links_row" valign="middle">
          <input type="checkbox" id="selectr-link-<?php echo $row['link_id']; ?>" name="select_link[]" value="<?php echo $row['link_id']; ?>" style="float:left;margin-top:3px;">
          <span style="float:left;width:25px;height:20px;margin: 0 3px;text-align:center;font-size: 20px;line-height: 22px;color: #009688;"><?php if($row['link_type'] == "Iframe"){ echo "<i class='fa fa-tv'></i>"; } elseif($row['link_type'] == "Direct"){ echo "<i class='fa fa-globe'></i>"; } ?></span>
          <span class="spanInMobile" style="float:left;height:20px;margin-right:5px;"><?php echo $row['link_url']; ?></span>
        </td>
        <td valign="middle">
          <?php echo $row['posted_by']; ?>
        </td>
        <td valign="middle" class="text-right">
        <?php $id = $row['link_id']; $status = $row['link_status']; if($status == '0'){ ?>
          <span title="Enable" class="disabled-entry" id="enable_link[]" data-id="<?php echo $row['link_id']; ?>"></span>
        <?php } elseif($status == '1'){ ?>
          <span title="Disable" class="enabled-entry" id="disable_link[]" data-id="<?php echo $row['link_id']; ?>"></span>
        <?php } ?>
          <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#enable_link').CLICK(function(){
                  var link_id = $('#enable_link').attr('data-id');
                    $.ajax({
                      url: "../src/ajax/enable_link.php",
                      method: "post",
                      data: {link_id:link_id},
                      success: function(data){
                        $('#links_list').html(data);
                      }
                    });
                  });

              });
            });
          </script>
          <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#disable_link').click(function(){
                var link_id = $('#disable_link').attr('data-id');
                $.ajax({
                  url: "../src/ajax/disable_link.php",
                  method: "post",
                  data: {link_id:link_id},
                  success: function(data){
                    $('#links_list').html(data);
                  }
                });
              });
            });
          </script>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <?php } } ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>                
  </div>
```

** enable.php **

```
  <?php
  require_once ('../system/config.php');

  $link_id = $_POST['link_id'];
  $db->query("UPDATE `links` SET `link_status` = '1' WHERE `link_id` = '".$link_id."'");

  ?>
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <thead>
          <tr>
          <td>Link</td>
          <td>Posted By</td>
          <td></td>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <?php
          $rows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `links` ");
          $totalLinks = $rows->num_rows;
          if($totalLinks == 0){
              echo "<tr><td colspan='5'><div class='' style='font-size: 16px;color: #F44336;background: #fff;width: fit-content;margin-left: 4px;'><i class='fa fa-meh-o'></i> <b>Error :</b> No LINK Has Been Added Yet.</div></td></tr>";
          } else {
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) {
          ?>
          <tr>
            <td id="links_row" valign="middle">
              <input type="checkbox" id="selectr-link-<?php echo $row['link_id']; ?>" name="select_link[]" value="<?php echo $row['link_id']; ?>" style="float:left;margin-top:3px;">
              <span style="float:left;width:25px;height:20px;margin: 0 3px;text-align:center;font-size: 20px;line-height: 22px;color: #009688;"><?php if($row['link_type'] == "Iframe"){ echo "<i class='fa fa-tv'></i>"; } elseif($row['link_type'] == "Direct"){ echo "<i class='fa fa-globe'></i>"; } ?></span>
              <span class="spanInMobile" style="float:left;height:20px;margin-right:5px;"><?php echo $row['link_url']; ?></span>
            </td>
            <td valign="middle">
              <?php echo $row['posted_by']; ?>
            </td>
            <td valign="middle" class="text-right">
            <?php $id = $row['link_id']; $status = $row['link_status']; if($status == '0'){ ?>
              <span title="Enable" class="disabled-entry" id="enable_link[]" data-id="<?php echo $row['link_id']; ?>"></span>
            <?php } elseif($status == '1'){ ?>
              <span title="Disable" class="enabled-entry" id="disable_link[]" data-id="<?php echo $row['link_id']; ?>"></span>
            <?php } ?>
              <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                  $('#enable_link').click(function(){
                    var link_id = $('#enable_link').attr('data-id');

                    $.ajax({
                      url: "../src/ajax/enable_link.php",
                      method: "post",
                      data: {link_id:link_id},
                      success: function(data){
                        $('#links_list').html(data);
                      }
                    });
                  });
                });
              </script>
              <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                  $('#disable_link').click(function(){
                    var link_id = $('#disable_link').attr('data-id');

                    $.ajax({
                      url: "../src/ajax/disable_link.php",
                      method: "post",
                      data: {link_id:link_id},
                      success: function(data){
                        $('#links_list').html(data);
                      }
                    });
                  });
                });
              </script>
            </td>
          </tr>
      <?php } } ?>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

It works only if the first row was been enabled and then the second one... ect but if you want to enable the 2nd row for example it won't work until you enable the first one

I tried with each() function but I am not sure that the code was right written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use same ID for pointing multiple elements in DOM, instead use CLASS.

so change your click event binding to a class instead of ID

**Example**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
                      $('.enabled-entry').click(function(){
                        var link_id = $(this).attr('data-id');

                        $.ajax({
                          url: "../src/ajax/enable_link.php",
                          method: "post",
                          data: {link_id:link_id},
                          success: function(data){
                            $('#links_list').html(data);
                          }
                        });
                      });
                    });
```

Also add this script after `while` loop

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply i will test it right now i got same advice from another guy i will give you a feedback after testing it thanks again flames

Comment: thanks for your answer it works with me without adding the for loop

Comment: if you don't mind i have a question is it possible to add the for loop with jquery or need to use each() function

Comment: Glad to here that.  No need to use `each()` or `for`  simply put both two scripts after the php while loop, when using class for jQuery binding it will automatically bind to all the elements with that class.